# How to time svg animations in a sequence?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, snap.svg

I am trying to improve my javascript with svg animations.

What I am trying to accomplish is have red circles flow from the bottom to the top line in a sequence (when bottom line is complete it begins on the line above) and the green circles to flow from the bottom line out to all the side lines.

Do I need to use javascript promises? Is settimeout an alright approach? If so, why are my animations appearing to be glitchy and not completing?

```
setInterval(function animOn(){
  if( animating ) {
    Snap.animate(0, bot_line, function( value ) {
       movePoint = south_line.getPointAtLength( value );
       redCircle.attr({ cy: movePoint.y, cx: movePoint.x }); 
      // move along path via cx & cy attributes
    }, 1000,mina.easeinout);

    Snap.animate(0, east, function( value ) {
       movePoint = east_line.getPointAtLength( value );
       greenCircle.attr({ cx: movePoint.x, cy: movePoint.y  }); 
      // move along path via cx & cy attributes
    }, 1000,mina.easeinout);
  };
}, 1000);
```

JS FIDDLE
http://jsfiddle.net/4wLrjmcq/1/

Thank you

Comment: I changed your JS Fiddle to remove the setTimeout stuff and added a green circle moving across the east line and it moves pretty much smoothly and simultaneously with the red circle moving across the south line. I have a pretty fast computer though. I tried it in Chrome and Firefox and it was ok. So it might just be performance issues. The only stutter I saw was when it started the animation before the page was fully loaded, so you might want to make sure you don't start the animation until after the page has loaded. This JS Fiddle runs smoothly for me: http://jsfiddle.net/kgxLkwh7/

Comment: If you want them in a sequence, you can use the callbacks (last animation argument) from one animation to call the next once its finished.

Comment: @Ian Would you be able to give an example on how that would work?

Comment: @PeterHaight Thanks for the explanation and the JSFiddle. I have been able to get the lines to move across without a stutter, the issue I am having is having them repeat

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kgxLkwh7/1/

Comment: @Ian Ah, okay I think I understand what you mean when referring to callbacks. If I had the animation looping like this http://jsfiddle.net/4wLrjmcq/5/  - how would the callbacks work if there are multiple animations at a time? ie. multiple red/green on bottom line going up to trigger the callbacks or to keep the whole thing as a loop

Comment: Get them to call each other, like http://jsfiddle.net/4wLrjmcq/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the callback function feature of Snaps animation. The last parameter is the function to run once the animation is complete.

So create some functions, eg animOn and animGreen, and then add the function name to the end of the animation call.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4wLrjmcq/7)

```
function animOn(){
  if( animating ) {
    Snap.animate(0, bot_line, function( value ) {
       movePoint = south_line.getPointAtLength( value );
       redCircle.attr({ cy: movePoint.y, cx: movePoint.x }); 
      // move along path via cx & cy attributes
    }, 1000,mina.easeinout);

    Snap.animate(0, east, function( value ) {
       movePoint = east_line.getPointAtLength( value );
       greenCircle.attr({ cx: movePoint.x, cy: movePoint.y  }); 
      // move along path via cx & cy attributes
    }, 1000,mina.easeinout, animGreen);
  };
};

function animGreen(){
  if( animating ) {
    Snap.animate(0, bot_line, function( value ) {
       movePoint = south_line.getPointAtLength( value );
       greenCircle.attr({ cy: movePoint.y, cx: movePoint.x }); 
      // move along path via cx & cy attributes
    }, 700,mina.easeinout, animOn);
  };
};

animOn();
```